# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout not always collapsing

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` that I want to use to show a header section on top of a `RecyclerView`. In the wanted behaviour, both have to be scrolled together:

[image: wanted]

The idea is to place the header in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `scroll` and `enterAlwaysCollapsed` flags:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:scrimAnimationDuration="0">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- other header elements -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_option_post"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, the header (`CollapsingToolbarLayout`) not always collapses, allowing the `RecyclerView` content slide behind it. Sometimes the header collapses too late (for ex. when the firsts recyclerview items are already covered by the header), while other times it behaves as expected.

Comment: How about this? : `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"`

Comment: Tried, `snap` add the snap animation to the toolbarLayout but I'm still able to bring the recycleview behind it